# One javascript file kills all the others. Ways to avoid this?

Tags: javascript

I will not add any code in here. Just working on a project and not only this time, but frequently one javascript file kills the others, so I ussually in this situation looked for similar solution (lets say a different slider and etc.)

But are there any more ways to wrap up some how a javascript file that it wont interfere with the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your solution is namespaces.

```
var APP = {};
APP.namespace = function(sNamespace) {
    if ("undefined" == typeof APP[sNamespace]) {
        APP[sNamespace] = {};
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
APP.namespace("profile");
APP.profile.AskQuestionDialog = function(oConfigs) { ... }
```

DOM tree:

```
 -window
   -APP
     -profile
```

And you should define you namespace in beginning of each file using `APP.namespace()`

Answer (score 5):

Please provide more details of what exactly you mean - but I have a feeling.

**Use namespaces.**

If you're using a collective of different libraries it could happen that libraries have the same global name, if you're not using namespaces.

Example how collisions usually occur:

```
function dontdothis() { 
   alert("Foo"); 
} 
function dontdothis() { 
   alert("Bar"); 
} 
dontdothis();
```

Example how to avoid those collisions:

```
var myownspace={}; 
myownspace.dothis=function() { 
    alert("Foo"); 
} 
function dothis() { 
    alert("Bar"); 
} 
myownspace.dothis();
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, each desecrate chuck of JavaScript should be wrapped in a closure with an API that is exposed to the wide world through a single global (which has a non-generic name, so `YAHOO` is reasonable as it is unlikely to be used by something else, while `$` is awful).

This is known as [namespacing](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=namespacing+JavaScript)